# Excel export ASP.NET Max Value error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, max, export-to-excel

I have a web page where a button exports a GridView to excel, but if the number in the GridView is greater than 1517959113996300000 the value changes to 1517959113996300000 (the number is an important ID, it is not generated by our application, but from another DB)

Here is the code for the button:

```
try
    {
        DataTable dtVistorias = new DataTable();
        this.GridViewVistorias.PageSize = 500000;
        dtVistorias = GetFaturar();
        this.GridViewVistorias.DataSource = dtVistorias;
        this.GridViewVistorias.DataBind();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Faturamento.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter sWr = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hWr = new HtmlTextWriter(sWr);
        GridViewVistorias.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        GridViewVistorias.RenderControl(hWr);
        Response.Write(sWr.ToString());
        Response.End();
        this.GridViewVistorias.PageSize = 1000;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ucGlobal.PopUpClient(this.Page, "erro na geracao do  excel\n" + ex.Message);
    }

    GridViewVistorias.Columns[0].Visible = true;
```

This is the GridView cell content:

1517959113996303637

(As you can see, the value is greater than 15179591139963**00000**, it is 15179591139963**03637**)

And the Excel exported cell:

1517959113996300000

Please, help me! I have no idea what to do!

(I had some screenshots to upload, but I can't post images, sorry)

Comment: What about changing it to a string data type?

Comment: You are not exporting to Excel format. You're exporting the data as an HTML file and saving it with a `.xls` extension. There's a lot of issues associated with that. It would probably be better if you used a managed library such as Office XML SDK, EPPlus, or NPOI to generate actual `.xlsx` files.

Answer (score 0):

This number is exceeding the maximum number precision of Excel.  Converting the number to a string will correct the issue.

This can be done by adding a style to the output:

```
 Response.Write("<style>.text{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>");
 Response.Write(sWr.ToString());
```